# Session gets lost when share on facebook

Tags: facebook, session, facebook-sharer

I'm building a Facebook share functionality.

I have two pages called: 'allstars.php' and 'typo.php'

From the allstarpage I fill out a form, that data gets passed to the `SESSION['results']`. From there the user gets the possibility to share the data that is in the session by the following url:

```
<a class="facebook stemspeler" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bnlhandball.com%2Fallstars&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bnlhandball.com%2Ftypo.php?id='.$makeUniq.'&title=I%20voted%20for%20favorite%20all-star%20team&caption=www.bnlhandball.com&description=test">‌​Share</a>
```

This is just the standard sharer.php functionality provided by facebook and has 2 parameters (u) that goes to the targetlink from the share and the picture that leads to the image that has to be used in the share.

Within the page typo.php the SESSION data gets processed to an image like so:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    session_start();

    $linker_hoek = $_SESSION['results']['linker-hoek'];

    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    // Output to browser
    header('Content-Type: image/png');

    //WHITE BACKGROUND COLOR
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(1500, 999);

    //$im = imagecreatefrompng("images/lars.png");
    $im = imagecreatefrompng("sharetest.png");

    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

    // Set the background to be white
    //imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 900, 990, $test);

    // Path to our font file
    $font       = 'fonts/DINPro-Medium.ttf';
    $fontSize   = 44;
    $angle      = 0;

    //$keeper = "'".$_SESSION['results']['linker-hoek']."'";



    $x = 80;
    $y = 200;
    // Write it
    imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $angle, $x, $y, $white, $font, 'test');


    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

When I got directly to the typo.php page It shows the content that is in the SESSION['results']. But when this page gets executed by the facebook sharer link (See codeblock on top of this page) the SESSION variable results isn't available anymore (Facebook ofcourse opens this URL itself). 
Anybody can help me to get the SESSION variables passed to the page that facebook opens?

Would be really great! Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Of course the session data is not available without the session id. And the id by default gets stored in a cookie. // This should not be implemented using sessions in the first place. Facebook will not request the URL only once, but repeatedly in the future to see if the data has changed. You should store the data permanently on your server somehow.

Comment: Hi Cbroe, Thanks for your comment. How could I make sure that facebook gets the right data? I'm not allowed to pass more parameters than the few that facebook allowes?

Comment: Use a GET parameter that allows you to fetch the data from wherever you have stored it.

Comment: That does not work in this case because the typo file generates a image from values that the user inputted. When doing it this way how, how do I combine the right user input to the right user share? Thanks for your help!

Comment: So, pass the values to that script via GET, instead of reading them from the session …?